# Make a JavaScript class from a different file accessible in the lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

How could I make a JavaScript class from a different file accessible in the arbitrary lightning controller?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812757/how-to-instantiate-a-javascript-class-in-another-js-file) question from SO, but it does not help me.

So, the best way I was able to come up with is to create a class in helper or `.js` static resource and then return it when needed to the controller. Are there better approaches you may know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load JavaScript libraries (whether your own or a third party's) as Static Resources. They're then available to your Lightning component controllers by using the [`<ltng:require>` component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm). Here's an example from one of my projects that uses [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) mapping:

**Component XML Markup**

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Leaflet + '/leaflet.css'}" 
              scripts="{! $Resource.Leaflet + '/leaflet-src.js'}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{! c.onScriptsLoaded }" />
```

**Component JavaScript Controller**

```
onScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    var m = L.map(component.find('map').getElement(), {zoomControl: true,zoom:1,zoomAnimation:false,fadeAnimation:true,markerZoomAnimation:true}).setView([39.9537069, -75.1649369], 11);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
    }).addTo(m);
    component.set('v.map', m);
    helper.checkLoadingProgress(component, event, helper);
},
```

Note that the libraries are loaded *asynchronously*, and a named handler function in your controller is called when the library becomes available.

Each component is separated from its fellows, so you need to apply `<ltng:require>` in each component where you're making use of your external script file, and remember that you cannot count on the library being available until your `afterScriptsLoaded` handler gets called.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried uploading that JS file as a static resource and including it in your component markup via [ltng:require](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation)? Then you will be able to reference any methods within that JS file in your Controller JS. Also notice that there is an `afterScriptsLoaded` parameter that could be used to call any method AFTER the script has been loaded.

```
<aura:component>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doSomethingAfterScriptsLoaded}"/>

<!-- Do something here -->

</aura:component>
```